# Is this a possible formula? Trying to have multiple picklist values be flagged if true in 1 formula. Looking to get 4 of these formulas into 1 formula

Tags: formula

```
IF(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Current_Option_Year__c, "3"),
        ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.of_Option_Years__c, "3")
    ),
    "Recompete",
    Null
)
AND(
IF(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Current_Option_Year__c, "4"),
        ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.of_Option_Years__c, "4")
    ),
    "Recompete",
    Null
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it:

```
IF (
  AND (
    OR(
      ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Current_Option_Year__c, "1"),
      ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Current_Option_Year__c, "2"),
      ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Current_Option_Year__c, "3"),
      ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Current_Option_Year__c, "4")
    ),
    TEXT(Opportunity.Current_Option_Year__c) = 
    TEXT(Opportunity.of_Option_Years__c)
  ),
  "Recompete",
  ""
)
```

explanation: if the first field is 1-4 and the second field matches, then that satisfies the condition. I forget if you need to wrap `TEXT` around the values in the second section.